# Error: Must use import to load ES Module - MikroOrm and Typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, mikro-orm

I'm trying to initialize a mikrorm setup to handle my postgres DB, but I fail to run my run-dev script due to ESM compilation error:

```
> yarn dev     
Error: Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Itay\Desktop\anewproj\dastack\server\src\index.ts
```

I delved deep into what can be the issue if it's tsconfig stuff that had to be changed or a loose import but sadly i didn't find anything pointing to it being in these files (index.ts, mikro-orm.config.ts)

I'm using the latest node version:

```
node -v
v18.7.0
```

and this version of yarn:

```
yarn -v
1.22.19
```

Also, I stumble into a very simillar error when I'm trying to run migrations through the cli tool:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module
```

## these are the files i've been working on:

#### index.ts

```
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import microConfig from './mikro-orm.config';

const main = async () => {
    const orm = await MikroORM.init(microConfig);
    
    const post = orm.em.create(Post, {title: 'my first dummpy post', createdAt: new Date(), updatedAt: new Date()});
    await orm.em.persistAndFlush(post);

    console.log("-----------sql 2 --------")
    await orm.em.nativeInsert(Post, {title: "second post with other insert"});

}

main().catch(err => {
    console.error(err)
})
```

#### mikto-orm.config.ts

```
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
import path from "path";

export default {
    
    migrations: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, "./migrations"),
    pattern: /^[\w]+\d+\.[tj]$/,
    },
    entities: [Post],
    dbName:"fakereddit",
    type:"postgresql",
    debug:!__prod__,
    
} as Parameters<typeof MikroORM.init>[0];
```

#### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2021",
    "module": "ESNext",
    "lib": ["dom", "ESNext", "esnext.asynciterable"],
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "strictFunctionTypes": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "strict": true
  },
  "ts-node": {
    "esm": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["./src/**/*.tsx", "./src/**/*.ts"]
}
```

Hope there's a way to fix this without nuking everything

Answer (score 0):

This is now handled automatically in MikroORM v5.4+

---

I would rather discourage use of ES modules if you plan on using classes for e
ntity definition and the default reflect-metadata, as you will fall into issues with circular dependencies easily. With ts-morph or EntitySchema it might work, but there will be other issues on the way, many dependencies are not ESM ready just yet IMHO.

But if you still want to try, you can make MikroORM use dynamic imports via `MIKRO_ORM_DYNAMIC_IMPORTS=1` env var.

You can also see the JS example repository that uses ES modules with `EntitySchema`:

https://github.com/mikro-orm/express-js-example-app

(it uses the [`.env`](https://github.com/mikro-orm/express-js-example-app/blob/master/.env#L1) file to set this)

edit: next version of MikroORM (5.3.2 or above) will handle this automatically, `MIKRO_ORM_DYNAMIC_IMPORTS` won't be needed.